# Best Datatype For A Collection

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to track "events" alongside the user account and I'd prefer not adding an entire database table for it.

What is the best datatype to store a collection/array of integers?

I was thinking I could use a text and just parse the values into an array, but there has to be a more effective way.

{1,6,18,427,293}

^ Assume I have an array similar to this, but it can be smaller or it could be much longer it just depends on the user.

This is basically What I am trying to create

Users

```
Id  |  Name   |  Events
0     James     {1,2}
1     Kitty     {0}
2     Mark      {1,3}
3     Adam      {1,2,3}
```

Events

```
Id    |  Name   |  Location |  Date
0       Event 1     Here      Tommorow
1       Event 2     There     Yesterday
2       Event 3     Around    Eventually
3       Event 4     Near      Someday
```

the events field on users, what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Don't store data like that in an `RDBMS`.  Create the new table, it will save you a lot of headache down the road...

Comment: What happens when you want to look up records where the third one is 18?

Comment: it just seems so silly to have a table that consists of two fields. {AccountID, EventIndex}

Comment: Please tell us how to evaluate "best"? As the other commenters say, the standard way of handling this is a new table, so if that doesn't work for you, how do we evaluate alternatives?

Comment: Not silly.. relational.

Comment: What you're doing (I presume, without being aware of it) is called _denormalization_. The term itself can be recursively defined as the opposite of _normalization_. I'd suggest that you invest 10 min of your life reading up on that and especially what 1-N and N-1 and N-M relationships are and how normalized relational databases model them. At worst you'll have wasted 10 min. At best you'll be slightly less ignorant and will avoid calling a _table with two fields_ a silly one. HTH.

Comment: Let me give you one (of many) example(s) why using a table with only two fields is far from silly: Your model, ie., storing `{1,2,3}` has no way of ensuring that either `1`, `2` or `3` indeed refers to an actual row of the `events` table. Moreover, storing `{1,2,2,2,3,3}` would also be a valid collection but surely you wouldn't want to allow duplicates. These are two points that can be easily addressed if you stick to a normalized schema.

Comment: Possibly off topic, but postgresql supports the array type into the table (so you can query the nth position...) in the case of MySQL, I would not recommend you storing lists into a column (It may look like a good idea now, but future you will not like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This violates the first normal form:

```
First normal form (1NF) is a property of a relation in a relational database. 
A relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains
only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single
value from that domain.
```

Your `User.Events` column is not atomic because it contains multiple values in a business sens.

The solution here is to create another table, called a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), which is the classical way to represent a N:N relationship. (usually named table1name_table2name)

This table contains references to both of your tables:

```
CREATE TABLE User_Event (
    UserId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(Id),
    EventId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Event(Id),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserId, EventId)
)
```

Based on your example, the values of this table would be:

```
UserId  |  EventId
0          1
0          2
1          0
2          1
2          3
3          1
3          2
3          3
```

*Edit: Added a primary key to the junction table, thanks to okiharaherbst's comment.*

Comment: For completeness, you should also uniquely index the pair `(user_id, event_id)`.